# Angular download de QR Code

Tags: javascript, angular, download, qrcode

Instalei essa biblioteca: npm i angularx-qrcode

Adicionei o componente abaixo no component.html:

```
<qrcode id='meuQRCode' [qrdata]="defineQRCode()" [width]="256"[errorCorrectionLevel]="'M'">
</qrcode>
```

E criei o método defineQRCode no component.ts:

```
defineQRCode(){
    return "teste";
}
```

A imagem do QR Code foi gerada corretamente, como posso criar um botão para download da mesma?

Answer (score -2):

Consegui instalando essa biblioteca:

- npm install html2canvas

E para exportar usei esse código:

```
const qr_code = document.getElementById("meuQRCode");
html2canvas(qr_code).then(function(canvas) {
    canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
        let link = document.createElement("a");
        link.download = "image.png";
        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.click();
    },'image/jpeg');
});
```